# Is any kind of energy emitted by a body during its motion

Tags: energy, waves, orbital-motion, oscillators

Just out of curiosity does an object moving at an arbitrary speed emit some sort of waves/energies?

*Consider two cases-Body in earths orbit and body inside earths atmosphere.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it depends on what kind of object is being considered.  Any macroscopic object that carries heat will emit radiation.  If it is large enough and complicated enough to act as a black body it will emit a continuous spectrum of black body radiation as @anna v pointed out.  A single neutron, though, does not carry heat so would not emit black body radiation.

Any *accelerated* object will emit radiation: A charged massive accelerated object will emit electromagnetic and gravitational radiation. If it is not charged, it will only emit gravitational radiation (though maybe Hawking would have argued the possibility that, at an incredibly small rate, *all* kinds of radiation would be emitted). This would include, for example, an object moving in orbit around the Sun because curved-path motion is accelerated motion.

An object moving at a constant velocity in an otherwise empty universe would not emit radiation of any kind other than black body (heat) radiation.  If the object is a point particle, which cannot carry heat, it would not emit black body radiation or any other kind of radiation.  However, if there is any other object in the universe that it can interact with (e.g., the Sun), that interaction will cause its path to curve and therefore the motion will be accelerated -- and at least gravitational radiation will be emitted.  At least in the case of electromagnetic interactions, there would also be an exchange of virtual photons which some people might call a kind of radiation.

NOTE: Gravitational radiation emitted by anything substantially less massive, or accelerating at a substantially lesser rate, than merging neutron stars, is far too weak to be detectable by any current technology.

The speed of light is effectively reduced in any medium like air, water, glass, etc. If a charged particle passes through such a medium at a speed *greater than the effective light speed*, it will emit Cherenkov radiation.  Cherenkov radiation is an electromagnetic shock wave analogous to the acoustic shock wave produced when a bullet moves faster than the speed of sound. Cherenkov radiation is easily detectable. [Cherenkov radiation](https://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/hfm/CosmicRay/ChLight/Cherenkov.html)

Answer (score 2):

All neutral , as the one you posit, bodies, whether moving or not, emit [black body radiation.](http://www.sun.org/encyclopedia/black-body-radiation)

[image: black body]

> Wien's displacement law showing the relationship between emitted radiation and the temperature of a black body, Source: Wikimedia Commons user Sch, adapted by Sun.org

Black body radiation is one of observations that necessitated the introduction of quantum mechanics. Note that room temperature is about 300k, which makes the [wavelength of order of microns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum) , infrared.

When motion enters, there will be [Doppler shif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect)t to this radiation.

Answer (score 1):

Particles emit photons while accelerated. In general moving charges emit EM fields and a body consisted of those should emit something equivalent of an EM field. Think of a magnet passing through a coil for example.

Acceleration changes a lot in our approach as well. Accelerated observers will detect blackbody radiation from the vacuum as well, the opposite of what you asked. This is called Unruh radiation, very similar to Hawking radiation from BHs.

Lastly, bodies in motion and especially in orbit emit gravitational waves as well, however only waves from massive bodies can be detected with current technology.

Comment: Charged particles, emit photons under  acceleration, not neutral ones, (even if  they contain charges in the atoms and molecules).